# Calling a method on an object retrieved from Dictionary JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, casting, javascript-objects

I am trying to fill a Dictionary (JavaScript object) and retrieve values (custom objects/classes) from it using a string index. Then once I get the value from the dictionary, I need to invoke a method on this object. Unfortunately, that does not work because once it is being retrieved from the Dictionary,  it is just a simple object (`typeof` returns "object").

So the thing I'm trying to do is to cast to the object type that was initially pushed into the dictionary, which is in my case: `google.visualization.Gauge`. ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge#Data_Format))

I tried to use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) but that did not work for me. Below is my code:

```
var _gauges = {};

var methods = {
    init: function (options) {

        var containers = this;

        if (containers != null && containers != undefined && containers.length > 0) {
            containers.each(function (index, elem) {

                var id = $(elem).attr('id');
                var name = $(elem).data('name');
                var value = $(elem).data('value');

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            [name, value]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    width: 400, height: 120,
                    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
                    yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90,
                    minorTicks: 5
                };
                var cont = document.getElementById(id);
                var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(cont);
                _gauges[name] = chart;
                chart.draw(data, options);
            });
        }

    },
    setValue: function (gaugeName, newValue) {
        var thisGauge = _gauges[gaugeName];
        if (thisGauge) {
            thisGauge.setCell(0, 1, newValue);
            //var tmp = Object.create(google.visualization.Gauge, thisGauge);
            //tmp.setCell(0, 1, newValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *All* objects in JavaScript are "just simple Objects".

Comment: What error are you receiving if you call the object directly without attempting casting?

Comment: I understand, but how do I call a method defined on a *simple object*?

Comment: Have you tried thisGauge.setCell(...);? Does it produce an error?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got `thisGauge.setCell is not a function`

Comment: You should post the code that puts things into the `_gauges` array.

Comment: I don't see a "setCell" method in that documentation. The only two methods listed are "draw" and "clearChart".

Comment: This is seriously not a good day for me to code... @Pointy, please include your last comment in an answer so I could accept it. Thanks a lot and sorry for the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two things:

1. If one of those "Gauge" objects is really getting put into the array correctly, when you get it back out it will emerge unscathed and you can just use it directly; no "casting" necessary.
2. According to the documentation you linked, there is no "setCell" method :-)

Comment: Answer accepted. I did not even need to cast, thanks a lot :)